# Find partial content of text on page, then return the full contents of that <div> in Python with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been struggling with how to accomplish this.

I need Selenium to find the partial content of text on a page and give me the full content.

My page, somewhere on it says "http://some.website/r@nd0mlyg3neratedt3xt". We'll assume "r@nd0mlyg3neratedt3xt" is constantly changing to other names, but there's never more than one instance of it on the page at a time.

So I'd search for something like "http://some.website/", it would find where that exists on the page, and then return "http://some.website/r@nd0mlyg3neratedt3xt". The text I'm looking for would be the full content of the `<div>`.

Only way I could think was find the text, check the ID of the `<div>` it's in, return that ID, and then use the ID to return the text.  But I couldn't figure out how to get the ID of the partial text's location.

EDIT:  I should also point out that the ID has been randomly generated.  So there's not much to grab on to.

Here's what I'm looking at in the page:

```
<div id="yxi_350111162360070455_2385" class="link wx-label"><span>http://some.website/r@nd0mlyg3neratedt3xt</span></div>
```

I'd like to basically get that link.  some.website will never change, but the characters at the end do.

EDITED:  Clarity, remove the Hello My Name Is part, and referencing the css directly.

Comment: Can you please add the html?

Comment: just added more info

Comment: edited for clarity

Comment: "r@nd0mlyg3neratedt3xt" is this a button, link, or something else? on page http://some.website/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know a selector that is specific enough to return at least a list of matching elements (e.g. a class named 'wx-label', as in your example), one of which has the text you are looking for, you can do the following to get the full text of the correct element:

```
#### Assume driver is your webdriver instance

text = 'http://some.website'
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class('wx-label')

for element in elements:
    if text in element.text:
        print element.text
```

Comment: giving this a try now

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="ink wx-label"]/span[contains(text(), "http://some.website"]')
```

Comment: Sorry, i was trying to give a simpler example, but then just followed it up with the actual situation.  That actually didn't seem to work.  It kept returning nothing, no matter what I replaced the text with.

Comment: What I'm actually looking for is this:  "http://some.website/r@nd0mlyg3neratedt3xt" -- but i ONLY want to find it based on "some.website"